# ASP.NET Encoding Syntax(<%#: %>) giving me error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanted to use ASP.NET encoding feature. If I have

```
<h3><%#: Eval("Header")%></h3>
```

Then it gives me this error,

> System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'Header'.

Why does it give me this error? Note, `<%# Eval("Header")%>` works but this does not `<%#: Eval("Header")%>`(note the colon :)

I was able to solve the issue, Actually I have `DataSource="<%#: Product.relatedProduct %>"` before  `<%# Eval("Header")%>`. When I remove the colon from `DataSource="<%#: Product.relatedProduct %>"`, everythings works. Weird that why ASP.NET showing error on `<%# Eval("Header")%>` instead of `DataSource="<%#: Product.relatedProduct %>"`

In Local when targeting 4.0, <%#: works but in server it shows compile time error.

Comment: You have bound your control to a 'Char', which has no such property as 'Header'. Post your binding code.

Comment: @AntP, `<%# Eval("Header")%>` works but this does not `<%#: Eval("Header")%>`(note the colon :)

Comment: What version of Asp.Net do you have installed? I think the syntax is for `4.5`?

Comment: @codingbiz, I am using 4.0, but changing into 4.5 does not effect any thing?

Comment: @codingbiz, Antp Thanks I have solved the issue. See above